# GetCurrentPlace of Google maps to ListView

Tags: android, google-maps, listview

I get information of nearby places , and want to make their list , but it does not work, i tried do adapter,list save data in list and set in adapter, you can see it in code. please tell me how i must do it?

Place detect:

```
PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
            .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
            for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                Log.i(TAG, String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %g",
                        placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                        placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
                        listForAd.add(String.valueOf(placeLikelihood)); //it how i try to set list, but not work.


            }
            likelyPlaces.release();
        }
    });
```

Adapter what i try:

```
 final ArrayList<String> listForAd = new ArrayList<>(); //create list,
 // I try to write the data above it

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listForAd );
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Data from Log:

```
 03-13 13:18:30.982 8950-8950/com.dmitriy.azarenko.thisifbars I/tag: Place       'ПП ОХОРОННЕ АГЕНТСТВО ЩИТ-2' has likelihood: 0,100000
03-13 13:18:30.983 8950-8950/com.dmitriy.azarenko.thisifbars I/tag: Place 'Спортивно-оздоровительный комплекс "Олимпийский"' has likelihood: 0,100000
03-13 13:18:30.984 8950-8950/com.dmitriy.azarenko.thisifbars I/tag: Place 'ТОВ А.Д.С.' has likelihood: 0,100000
03-13 13:18:30.985 8950-8950/com.dmitriy.azarenko.thisifbars I/tag: Place 'ул. Олимпийская' has likelihood: 0,0500000
03-13 13:18:30.987 8950-8950/com.dmitriy.azarenko.thisifbars I/tag: Place 'Надежда' has likelihood: 0,0500000
03-13 13:18:30.988 8950-8950/com.dmitriy.azarenko.thisifbars I/tag: Place 'Михайлик л. Н., част. Предпр-тель' has likelihood: 0,0500000
03-13 13:18:30.988 8950-8950/com.dmitriy.azarenko.thisifbars I/tag: Place 'Межшкольный Учебно-производственный Комбинат №5 Фрунз. р-на' has likelihood: 0,00000
03-13 13:18:30.989 8950-8950/com.dmitriy.azarenko.thisifbars I/tag: Place 'ул. Олимпийская' has likelihood: 0,00000
03-13 13:18:30.989 8950-8950/com.dmitriy.azarenko.thisifbars I/tag: Place '5-я Городская Поликлиника' has likelihood: 0,00000
03-13 13:18:30.990 8950-8950/com.dmitriy.azarenko.thisifbars I/tag: Place 'ул. Ковтуна' has likelihood: 0,00000
03-13 13:18:30.990 8950-8950/com.dmitriy.azarenko.thisifbars I/tag: Place 'Верона, Лтд, Ф., ООО' has likelihood: 0,00000
03-13 13:18:30.991 8950-8950/com.dmitriy.azarenko.thisifbars I/tag: Place 'Аналитика' has likelihood: 0,00000
03-13 13:18:30.991 8950-8950/com.dmitriy.azarenko.thisifbars I/tag: Place 'ЧП Панченко Д.С.' has likelihood: 0,00000
03-13 13:18:30.991 8950-8950/com.dmitriy.azarenko.thisifbars I/tag: Place 'ООО "Баланс"' has likelihood: 0,00000
03-13 13:18:30.993 8950-8950/com.dmitriy.azarenko.thisifbars I/tag: Place 'ул. Олимпийская' has likelihood: 0,00000
03-13 13:18:30.993 8950-8950/com.dmitriy.azarenko.thisifbars I/tag: Place 'Отель SV Park Hotel' has likelihood: 0,00000
03-13 13:18:30.994 8950-8950/com.dmitriy.azarenko.thisifbars I/tag: Place 'Маршал' has likelihood: 0,00000
03-13 13:18:30.994 8950-8950/com.dmitriy.azarenko.thisifbars I/tag: Place 'ул. Олимпийская' has likelihood: 0,00000
03-13 13:18:30.994 8950-8950/com.dmitriy.azarenko.thisifbars I/tag: Place 'Перспектива, Потребительский Кооператив' has likelihood: 0,00000
03-13 13:18:30.994 8950-8950/com.dmitriy.azarenko.thisifbars I/tag: Place 'электроинструмент' has likelihood: 0,00000
```

Comment: Not sure but this might be helpful to you: https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/pl/charmas/android/reactivelocation/sample/PlacesActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

The Google PlaceDetectionApi has the ability to get the list of nearby places around you by detecting your location automatically.So You have to send request to get list of nearby places like below

```
private void callPlaceDetectionApi() {
        Log.d(TAG, "callPlaceDetectionApi() called");
        PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
                .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
        result.setResultCallback(this);
    }
```

In OnResult Callback you can add this likelihood places into your own **NearbyPlace** model class

```
@Override
    public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResult() called with: " + "likelyPlaces = [" + likelyPlaces.toString() + "]");
        List<NearbyPlace> nearbyPlaces = new ArrayList<>();
        for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
            NearbyPlace nearbyPlace = new NearbyPlace();
            Log.i(TAG, String.format("Place '%s' with " +
                            "likelihood: %g",
                    placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                    placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
            nearbyPlace.setName(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName().toString());
            nearbyPlace.setLikelihood(placeLikelihood.getLikelihood());
            nearbyPlace.setAddress(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getAddress().toString());
            nearbyPlaces.add(nearbyPlace);
        }

    }
```

I have written a post on my blog [How to retrieve List of Nearby Places using PlaceDetectionApi](http://waleedsarwar.com/blog/how-to-retrieve-list-of-nearby-places-using-placedetectionapi-and-encapsulate-that-logic-in-loaders/).

Comment: data I received, I do not understand how to put them in a ListView

Comment: download the sample code from you will see how to put it in a list https://github.com/waleedsarwar86/NearByPlacesDemo